# Copy XML into OutputDirectory of Other Project

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I run this code in one C# project. The file is in the root of the project. Ant it has set Copy to output directory to copy always.

```
   XDocument fileConfigXml = XDocument.Load("FileConfig");
```

That project is being invoked from other project.

I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\SolutionName\OtherPriect\bin\Debug\FileConfig.xml'.
```

Can I copy xml file to the caller project or read it form its domestic project?

Comment: Where you written XDocument fileConfigXml = XDocument.Load("FileConfig");

Comment: @Ganesh It is in non executed project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML-File must be in the Project which is the executed program. Otherwise it will only copied to the Output-folder of the referenced Project. A reference to a project means, that you use the .dlls but not the other files.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable globally, move the code to load event(eg: Form1_load) of form and try again.